# How to communicate in OpenCart with PHP file on another server

Tags: php, json, opencart

We have a MySql database in a server. We want, after a final click, for OpenCart to send some data to a PHP file and wait for the answer (JSON).

For example: When the user pushes the button (*Pay Now*) to order we want to send some data to a server and receive some JSON data stating that you have 1 or more items, or you can't buy because the shop doesn't have any items of that product.

Can we do that with OpenCart?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.  You can send and receive json pretty easily with PHP or javascript and thus with opencart.  Which part are you less familiar with?  The layout of opencart or PHP/Javascript?

Comment: I'm a drupal developer (php) and now i would like to learn opencart. I dont now how i can say opencart to wait for a response and act depending from the json string.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check product availability - you can use

```
 $product['quantity']
```

in `

> catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php
>   `

as example

```
   $quantity=file_get_contents('http://api.url?product_id='.$product['product_id']);
    if ($product['quantity'] > (int)$quantity) {
       $this->data['error_warning'] = 'Product not available ';
                    }
```

Your api must answer a quantity of product.